# ¿Cómo se crea un Image Server?

Tags: html, lenguaje-agnóstico

¿Cómo puedo hacer un servidor de imágenes? Es decir, que mis imágenes tengan una URL y en vez de declararlas así:

```
<img src="pic_mountain.jpg" >
```

Que se vean así:

```
<img src="http://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg" alt="W3Schools.com">
```

¿Con una URL en especifico de mi pagina o con qué lenguaje de programación o backend se puede realizar (rubyonrails, django o php)?

Si tienen un ejemplo se lo agradecería mucho.

Comment: Dependiendo de la cantidad de imágenes y del tamaño, puedes montarlo de una manera u otra. Una de las más sencillas y baratas es montarte un blog de google, empezar una publicación, adjuntar las imágenes que quieras a esa publicación, pero no publicarla. Si miras el código html del borrador de la publicación verás como aparece su url y podrá ser usada como si estuviera en un servidor. **EDITO:** Como bien dice Álvaro usa Picassa para tener la url de las imagenes que tu quieras.

Comment: Hola @Jonni. Preguntas de este tipo que no están asociadas a un lenguaje de programación. Pero si deseas preguntar cómo lograrlo programáticamente, debes colocar un solo lenguaje de programación, no más.

Comment: Me sigue sin quedar muy clara la pregunta, ¿qué es lo que quieres hacer? ¿Quieres que las rutas a las imágenes sean absolutas en lugar de relativas?¿Quieres tener las imágenes en otro servidor diferente?¿Quieres crear tu propio servidor de imágenes?

Comment: una disculpa si no me exprese bien, mi intencion era saber acerca de lo que Muriano decia, referente a que necesitaba un servidor como apache o nginx etc, muchas gracias :) (perdon por la demora en mi respuesta)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No necesitas ninguna tecnología especial para hacer eso que quieres.

```
<img src="pic_mountain.jpg">
```

Esto es una ruta "relativa" que indica que la imagen está en el mismo directorio que el documento web que se está cargando, por ejemplo `index.html`. De esta manera, tendrías esta estructura

```
- Directorio raiz web
-- index.html
-- pic_mountain.jpg
```

Por el contrario:

```
<img src="http://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg" alt="W3Schools.com">
```

Es una ruta "absoluta", representa toda la dirección completa donde está alojado el recurso. Incluye esquema `http://`, host o servidor, `www.w3schools.com` y path o ruta `/images/w3schools_green.jpg` de esta manera, no es necesario que el documento web y el recurso estén en el mismo directorio. Ni siquiera en el mismo servidor.

Para hacer esto, necesitas un servidor web (apache, nginx, etc) aunque cualquiera de las opciones que te han comentado, como picassa, puede valer. Solamente ten en cuenta que a la hora de indicar el atributo `src` de la imagen, tendrás que poner estos tres elementos que te mencioné, `esquema o schema`, `servidor o host` y `ruta o path`.

Esto es igualmente aplicable al atributo `href` de los enlaces, que puede ser relativo o absoluto.

Comment: gracias :D, empece a usar dropbox por mientras para el almacenamiento de mis imagenes :)